# strpos me devuelve siempre 0 en esta regla

Tags: php

No entiendo el motivo por el que la siguiente regla me devuelve en este caso el valor 0. El código en PHP es este:

```
$contador = (strpos($posts[0]['Codigo_juego'],$usuario_color['siguiendo_juegos']) !== FALSE) ? 1 : 0;
```

Que da como resultado esto:

```
$contador = (strpos("c3kldkzbhncz","bzf7k34wnwc2;c3kldkzbhncz;") !== FALSE) ? 1 : 0; 
echo $contador; //me devuelve siempre 0;
```

La cadena que estoy buscando está dentro del string, me debería devolver el valor 1, pero me devuelve 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error es que el segundo parametro debe de estar contenido en el primero, como lo estas mostrando en tu código para que devuelva la posición debería estar de está forma

```
$contador = (strpos("bzf7k34wnwc2;c3kldkzbhncz;", "c3kldkzbhncz") !== FALSE) ? 1 : 0;
```

he aqui la documentación de la función `strpos`

http://php.net/manual/es/function.strpos.php

Comment: Me estaba volviendo loco mirando la condición del FALSE y ni me había fijado en que estaba al revés. ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

aquí te paso el script ya funcional solo para que cheques por fas que fue lo que le paso al tuyo saludos

```
$name = "dfgdgf;Paz;Lopez;";


$resultado = (strpos($name, "Alfredo") !== FALSE) ? 1 : 0;

echo $resultado; //da 0
```

el siguiente da uno por que si hay coincidencia

```
<?php

$name = "Alfredo;Paz;Lopez;";


$resultado = (strpos($name, "Alfredo") !== FALSE) ? 1 : 0;

echo $resultado;
```